# CountDistinct based on a condition from another column Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DF sample:

```
------------------+---------+
|           ticket_id|news_item|
+--------------------+---------+
|13001244822020121...|        1|
|13000386812020121...|        0|
|13000521120201212...|        0|
|13000578320201212...|        0|
|13000667320201212...|        0|
|13001430320201212...|        0|
|13001440320201212...|        0|
|13001497120201212...|        0|
|13001518420201212...|        0|
|13001117120201212...|        1|
```

What I want to do is count all the ticket_id based on the news_item column. So for example if the DF have 300 rows the desired output should be something like:

```
 new_column_name     |news_item|
+--------------------+---------+
|200                 |        1|
|100                 |        0|
```

The code I'm using is the following:

```
output = (df
          .groupby('is_lidl_plus','news_item')
          .agg(f.countDistinct('ticket_id').alias('total_tickets'),
            **f.countDistinct(f.when('news_item')==1)).alias('tickets_with_vouchure')**,
               f.round(f.sum('gross_spending'),2).alias('total_amount_spend'),
               f.round(f.avg('gross_spending'),2).alias('average_gross_amount_spend'),
               f.round(f.avg('net_spending'),2).alias('average_amount_spend')))
```

And the output from pyspark is:

> TypeError: when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant doing this instead? You want to count the number of ticket_id with news_item = 1 right?

```
f.countDistinct(
    f.when(
        f.col('news_item')==1,
        f.col('ticket_id')
    )
).alias('tickets_with_vouchure')
```

Comment: Hello @mck, yes! That was exactly what I wanted. Your solution worked perfectly. Thanks again!!!